# relationship with Entity Framework 5 and .net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I have a model like this :

```
namespace HiTech.Common.Models{
    public class CodeContext : DbContext
    {
        public CodeContext(): base("DefaultConnection"){}

        public DbSet<Code> Codes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CodeMember> CodeMembers { get; set; }
    }
    public class Code
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string EnDescription { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CodeMember> CodeMembers { get; set; }
    }

    public class CodeMember
    {

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int CodeId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CodeId")]
        public Code Code { get; set; }    }}
```

and I use CodeMember in there like this :

```
namespace HiTech.Sales.Customers.Models{
    public class CustomerContext : DbContext
    {
        public CustomerContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
    public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]

        public string CustCode { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("IndividualId")]
        public CodeMember Individual { get; set; }
        public int IndividualId { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

My questions are:

1. how I filter Individual from Code Id in my model (Not in controller like below code):

   ```
   public ActionResult Create()
   {
       ViewBag.IndividualId = new SelectList(
              db.CodeMembers.Where(p => p.Code.EnDescription == "Individual"),
                  "Id", "Description");
       return View();
   }
   ```
2. when I put CustomerModel in another Area , I can not load or save data with the followed error :

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name dbo.Customers'.
>   Source Error:
>   Line 56:             {
>   Line 57:                 db.Customers.Add(customer);
>   Line 58:                 db.SaveChanges();
>   Line 59:                 return RedirectToAction("Index");
>   Line 60:

Comment: How did you generate the database?

Comment: Database Generated automaticly . if tables not exist CodeFirst of data entity make them .

Comment: Exactly. Which context creates the database?

Comment: CodeContext create Code and CodeMember table . But CustomerContext can not create own table . you say I have to put them together in one Context ? I like to put them in different name space and different area . I want use them like Component

Comment: Of course there must be one context that knows all: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx

Comment: Thenk you . What about #1 question... can you help me about that ? I have a Code (as header) and CodeMember(as detail) and they joined together by Id(one to many join). I want to use some CodeMember in another model(like Customer) that filtered by Code Id . can I do it or I have to filter them in Controller ? Thanks Again

Comment: I summarized the above in an answer and added what I think is the answer to your first question.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your second question, the non-existent table. That is because you have two contexts that both know only parts of the complete data model. You can work with such [bounded contexts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx), but there should be one context that "knows" all, so it is able to generate the whole database.

As for the first question. If you mean if it's possible to combine `DbSet`s from different contexts in one (SQL) query the answer is no. If you want to create a query that combines `Customer` with `Code` through `CodeMember` you'll have to query the `Code + CodeMember` in one query and the `Customer` in a second query. But you can take a `CodeMember` from a `CodeContext` and attach it to a `CustomerContext` (make sure to detach it from the `CodeContext` first).